# Replace specific commas in a csv file

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

I have a file like this:

```
gene_id,transcript_id(s),length,effective_length,expected_count,TPM,FPKM,id
ENSG00000000003.14,ENST00000373020.8,ENST00000494424.1,ENST00000496771.5,ENST00000612152.4,ENST00000614008.4,2.23231E3,2.05961E3,2493,2.112E1,1.788E1,00065a62-5e18-4223-a884-12fca053a109
ENSG00000001084.10,ENST00000229416.10,ENST00000504353.1,ENST00000504525.1,ENST00000505197.1,ENST00000505294.5,ENST00000509541.5,ENST00000510837.5,ENST00000513939.5,ENST00000514004.5,ENST00000514373.2,ENST00000514933.1,ENST00000515580.1,ENST00000616923.4,3.09456E3,2.92186E3,3111,1.858E1,1.573E1,00065a62-5e18-4223-a884-12fca053a109
```

The problem is that instead of `,`, the file should've been tab delimited because the values starting from `ENST` (i.e. `transcript_id(s)`) are grouped in one column.

The number of `ENST IDs` is different in each line.

Each `ENST ID` has the same pattern: starts from ENST, followed by 11 digits followed by a period and then 1-3 digits: `^ENST[0-9]{11}[.][0-9]{1,3}`.

I want to convert all the comma's between ENST ids to a `:` or any other character to read this as a csv file. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine something as simple as

```
sed 's|,ENST|:ENST|g;s|:|,|' < /path/to/your/file
```

should work. No reason to over-complicate.

Comment: True. This also converts the first `,` after ENSG to `:` though.

Comment: Ok Thanks!! I did something like this: `sed -e 's/,ENST/:ENST/g' -e 's/:/,/' sample.csv`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't notice the first value was ENSG, not ENST. Will edit.